# regex for excluding text at end of string

Tags: regex

I have a regular expression (built in adobe javascript) which finds string which can be of varying length.

The part I need help with is when the string is found I need to exclude the extra characters at the end, which will always end with 1 1.

This is the expression:

```
var re = new RegExp(/WASH\sHANDLING\sPLANT\s[-A-z0-9 ]{2,90}/);
```

This is the result:

WASH HANDLING PLANT SIZING STATION SERVICES SHEET **1 1 75 MOR03 MUP POS SU W ST1205 DWG 0001**

I need to modify the regex to exclude the string in bold beginning with the 1 1.

Keep in mind the string searched for can be of varying length hence the {2,90}

Can anyone please advise assistance in modifying the REGEX to exclude all string from 1 1

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a positive lookahead and keep the same functionality:

```
/WASH\sHANDLING\sPLANT\s[-A-Za-z0-9 ]{2,90}(?=\b1 1\b)/
                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The `(?=\b1 1\b)` lookahead requires `1 1` as whole "word" after your match.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xBHxGB/1)

Also, note that `[A-z]` [matches more than just letters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29771926/3832970).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help much appreciated, the regex with the positive lookahead works and the string in bold is excluded.